Can I stop the function with a return if my func says it will return a list?
In this code, I want to read a JSON file and return its content in a list. If the JSON file does not exist, I want the function to end and print the file does not exist, but PyCharm says it expects to return a list. How can I do it well?
Here is the code:
def read_json_files(file: str) -> list:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            try:
                read_data = json.load(f)
                return read_data
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"{e}: the json had some errors, returning an emtpy list")
                return []
    else:
        print("the json doesn't exist, returning an empty list")
        return


The message says "returning an empty list", but you don't want to return an empty list?  What did you want to do instead?

"returning an empty list" does not correspond with return, which implicitly returns None. Either the return type (and the printed message) is wrong, or the return statement is wrong. Perhaps you should even throw an error.

You can do it. Type checks are not applied at runtime - meaning your code will run. You shouldn't do it, because when you are promising to return a list, you should return a list and not None (return without value is the same as return None).

You can either change the return type hint to -> list | None or change the last line to return [] so the function returns an empty list on all branches

You're not returning an empty list, should be return [] just like inside the except above

@JRiggles i want to return a list with the read data, but if the json file does not exist, i dont want to return anything, that means the script that uses this function will close,  using this list | None will work?

Yes, that "hints" that the function will return either a list or  None. As @jonrsharpe mentioned, return with nothing after it implicitly returns None (which is to say that a bare return and return None are functionally the same thing)

@JRiggles thank you, i will used, and if I ever have to return 3 different values, would I use | again? or is it bad to return more than 1 or 2 values?

Depending on the contents of the file you're reading, your function could return either None, an empty list, a non-empty list or a dictionary. My personal preference would be to remove the test for the file's existence and just try to open it. If it doesn't exist you'll get an exception which you could (maybe should?) manage in the calling code. In fact, you could even remove the try/except for the JSONDecodeError and manage that similarly

You would use that syntax if the function returns different types of values. An empty list [] is still a list, for example. But type hinting like that can get unwieldy - @SIGHUP's  suggestion is usually my preference too. Try stuff and handle exceptions accordingly.

Allowing the exception to be raised to the caller is a more Pythonic pattern (in my opinion - others may disagree).
Here's an example of how you could adapt your code:
import json

def read_json_file(filename: str) -> list | dict:
    with open(filename) as data:
        return json.load(data)

def main():
    filename = "foo.json"
    try:
        data = read_json_file(filename)
        if isinstance(data, list):
            ... # process response as a list
        else:
            ... # process response as a dictionary
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"{filename} does not exist")
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print(f"{filename} exists but is in the incorrect format")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

